# Use of undefined constant JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE - assumed 'JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE

Tags: php, json, laravel

In LogManager.php line 416:

````
Use of undefined constant JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE - assumed 'JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE'```
````

Comment: You should form your title/description as a question and provide more context that just copy/pasting your error message. If you put little value in asking a question you will find people don't want to put much effort into responding either.

Answer (score 0):

JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE was added in PHP 7.2.0. https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

Whatever code you are using is relying on PHP 7.2.0 (or higher). You need to ensure you are using the appropriate version of PHP for the libraries/packages you are using.

Comment: i am using laravel

Comment: @AbdulAmeer Laravel version requirements can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/

Comment: got this after updating php to 7.3

Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Illuminate\Http\json_decode()